# SetBypassCSP on new tab in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I'm opening the following html page in Puppeteer:

```html
<!-- head -->

<body>
    <a class="btn-tab" href="html_simple.html" target="_blank">new tab</a>
</body>

<!-- more web -->
```

Clicking on the button will open a new tab.

In my javascript code I have the following:

```
const context = page.browserContext();


context.on('targetcreated', async (target) => {
    const newPage = await target.page();
    if (newPage) {
        await newPage.setBypassCSP(true);
    }
});
```

However, when opening the new page, the CSP bypass is still disabled (throws a content security error when loading some scripts). I assume that this is because the `targetcreated` event is thrown after the new page navigation, and, as the Puppeteer docs states:

> NOTE CSP bypassing happens at the moment of CSP initialization rather then evaluation. Usually this means that page.setBypassCSP should be called before navigating to the domain.

Which seems to be the case, as executing `page.reload()` and `setBypassCSP` before loading these scripts seems to work.

My question is how to set bypassCSP to true on a tab opened by a web? Is there an event before loading content or global setup in Puppeteer that allows me to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/4764 this is not possible for now. The alternative being using .reload after the tab has been opened and setBypassCSP is set to true.

If the problem comes from `addScriptTag`, using evaluate instead would be an alternative to avoid CSP without bypass